# knockout updating observable not working for with

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout observable that maps to a select in the javascript. Based on the select value, it has a "with" binding for a div.

I need to set the value of observable in javascript, and the problem is that the div just never shows up. Here are the details:

The observable is bound to a select in the UI, and the selected value is an object:

```
 <select data-bind="options: Offers, 
                    optionsText: 'Offer', 
                    optionsCaption: 'Please Choose', 
                    value: SelectedOffer">
 </select>
```

When user selects a value, I have a div data bound using "with" that shows up under the select:

```
<div data-bind="with: SelectedOffer">
     ....
</div>
```

Now this works perfectly fine when I select a value in the UI.

When user checks a box, I am setting the observable value in javascript, and that also works:

```
event.SelectedOffer(myOffer);
```

I can see the offer I set in the select. The problem is that the div bound using "with" never shows up. If I choose something manually from the select, then it works fine again.

I have tried many different things to somehow let ko know that the value has changed, and it needs to show me the div, but nothing seems to work. I have used

```
valueHasMutated
valueWillMutate
ko.utils.triggerEvent
$(myselect).change()
```

Help!

Comment: It is hard to follow your question regarding what is not working. I was not able to repro your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ww9dK/. Can you maybe try to update/create a jsfiddle which shows your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and setting up the jsfiddle. I updated jsfiddle so that it now reproduces the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/ww9dK/5/. As you can see, and as you expected, it's more than what I stated in the original issue. I'm actually switching out the list. In my updated jsfiddle snippet, it shows that it works fine with the ui, but doesn't work well with javascript.

Comment: Ok, my issue is reproduced here: jsfiddle.net/ww9dK/13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is fixed!!! Thanks for the responses, esp nemesv's comment and setting up the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ww9dK/14/

```
var ViewModel = function()  {
var self = this;
   self.list1 = [{Offer: "Offer1"},{Offer: "Offer2"},{Offer: "Offer3"}];
   self.list2 = [{Offer: "Offer4"},{Offer: "Offer5"},{Offer: "Offer6"}];

   self.AlternateList = ko.observable(false);
   self.SelectedOffer = ko.observable();
   self.SelectedList = ko.observable(self.list1);

   self.selectSecond = function() {

     self.SelectedList(!self.AlternateList() ? self.list2: self.list1);
     self.SelectedOffer(!self.AlternateList() ? self.list2[0]: self.list1[0]);
   }
};
```

Bottom line is that my alternate list needed to be an observable. Resolved thanks to an awesome collegue's help. 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've confused a few things with KO

the `value:` on your select element will automatically set the SelectedOffer observable on your ViewModel. There is no need to manually set it which is what I understand you think you are doing with  `event.SelectedOffer(myOffer);` .

If you only wanted to update SelectedOffer when the user checked something, you would need to bind value on your select box to a different observable and then manually update your 'real' value

I've set up  http://jsfiddle.net/HLGKf/ to demonstrate how to set up a simplistic ViewModel and select box, as well as using the  `with:`  binding

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please see this http://jsfiddle.net/ww9dK/13/. This reproduces my issue. The issue is related to switching the list.

Comment: The issue is that you actually have a race condition on your 'checked' and 'event' bindings. 1. The event is setting the selected offer; 2. AlternateList is being toggled; 3. (2) is causing the list to change out from underneath the selected offer (you have an erroneous ! in your select second function). It is by some state error that the selection even shows up in the box.

It is best not to make any assumptions about the order that knockout will try to update observables. You make that assumption when calling selectSecond before you know the list has been changed by the checked binding.

Comment: I definitely think that not having that conditional in your options binding is a good thing, but just to illustrate my point: http://jsfiddle.net/kWTMx/2/ here I've moved the selectSecond call into a function that is guaranteed to fire AFTER AlternateList has been updated, from your 'event' binding on the checkbox